# How to modify the handles style of rc-slider range while active?

Tags: css, reactjs, rc-slider

I'm using the rc-slider range and I'm trying to use some style on it.

I have managed to change the color of the track and the handles, but I don't know how to change the color of the box-shadow while clicking on the handle.

I tried using classic css with selector, but they don't seem to recognize it.
And I don't think I can use the active state inline with :
`handleStyle={[{ borderColor: "#3643BA" }, { borderColor: "#3643BA" }]}`